# How to make VS Code not open a File Explorer window when opening files

Tags: macos, visual-studio-code

(I'm on a Mac). When I open files in VS Code using `CMD + O`, like shown in the image below.
I have a different machine where using `CMD + O` opens a small file explorer as an editable address bar instead (see other image). I haven't been able to figure out what settings options configures this.

How do I make my VS Code open the editable address bar instead of the system's default file explorer application when opening files?

[VSCode opens File Explorer window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W9nXz.png)

[VSCode opens an editable address bar and not a window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zV9pO.png)

I have been looking around in the `settings.json` for both machines but have been unable to find the difference which makes this change.

Comment: Perhaps it's not a setting but a plugin or keybinding?

Comment: You can go to keyboard shortcuts (CMD + K, then CMD + S) on source machine to check which actions binded to a combination

Comment: what is the OS of both machines and what version of VSC are you using on both machines

Answer (score 2):

The setting you're looking for is `files.simpleDialog.enable`. You can put the following in your [settings.json file](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/settings#_settingsjson):

```json
"files.simpleDialog.enable": true
```

The setting's description:

> Enables the simple file dialog. The simple file dialog replaces the system file dialog when enabled.